# How to get the array data inside Input::all() and store it as hasMany() relation to the actual record?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on a project and there is a table diagnostic. There is another table diagnostic_detail. diagnostic has a one to many relation with diagnostic_detail. The post data coming in the Diagnostic controller to make a new record has all the information about the diagnostic itself and an array of details to be pushed into the diagnostic_detail method.

Now it is simple to create the diagnostic record:

```
Diagnostic::create(Input::all());
```

But how do I take all the data for the detail and create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to loop and create the detail object manually. Try this:

```
$details = array();
foreach(Input::get('diagnostic_detail') as $detail){
    $details[] = new DiagnosticDetail($detail);
}
$diagnostic->details()->saveMany($details);
```

In this example, `DiagnosticDetail` is the model that is referenced by `hasMany()` and `details` is the hasMany relationship.

More information on [inserting related models](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

Comment: This is exactly what i have attempted. I was hoping there was a better way since it is cumbersome to validate in this way.

Comment: I know it's not very pretty but what is the problem with validation exactly?

Comment: For example i set the validations on the details and validate in the for loop, it will be hard to get which detail failed validation, right?

Comment: Hmm.. you could have another array `$errors` and save them in there. Maybe there is a better solution for this problem but there's no Laravel way to solve it as far as I know.